# Safe way to web scrape within VBA

Tags: vba, security, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I need to scrape some price data from a website. To get this done, I use the following snippet:

```
With http
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("sidebar-item-label")

    For i = 1 To topics.Length - 1
    str = topics(i).href
```

It works, but I am wondering how to secure the data, before assigning the `html response` to my variable `str`. To avoid malicious code get run on my windows machine, I need to validate, sanatize and escape the response data, before safe it to the variable and do the further stuff like string splitting and save it into my Excel spreadsheet.

Does anybody can help me with that? Do you need more informations?

Comment: It's not clear how you might expect assigning a value to a string variable to create any kind of security risk?  Can you provide an example of the type of thing you want to protect against?  In your code you assign `html.body.innerHTML = .responseText` and not to `str` though...

Comment: My goal is to get some data from a website, do some further stuff, like extract a small piece of data like prices to a excel cell. I want to protect excel from execute bad code, in the case that an attacker has placed malicous code on that side, that i was scraping.
And I am not a programmer - I am still learning it by myself in spare time.

Answer (score 0):

My code so far:

```
Dim objXmlHTTP as New XMLHTTP60, html as New HTMLDocument
Dim prices as IHTMLElementCollection

With objXmlHTTP
     .open "GET", URL, FALSE
     .send
     html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set prices = html.getElementsByClassName("MyClass")
```

After getting the data, I am looping through the collection and search for a specific string "price" and assign the data t/value of price to an Excel cell. So and to avoid that excel will execute any bad code, I want to validate, sanatize and escape the data, before saving the `html` data into Excel cell.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).